# UILabel's not properly changing text

Tags: swift, xcode, nsstring, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

Whenever I print out the Highscore or the score it prints out exactly as is. Whether it be 7 and 7 or 7 and 5.

When I pull up the simulator the text is changed to Hi... or Sc...
Rather than Highscore: x or Score: c

```
@IBOutlet var HS: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var S: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let HighscoreDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    let ScoreDefault = UserDefaults.standard
    print("Hi")
    if HighscoreDefault.value(forKey: "Highscore") != nil
    {
        let Highscore = HighscoreDefault.value(forKey: "Highscore") as! Int
        let Score = ScoreDefault.value(forKey: "Score") as! Int
        print(Highscore)
        print(Score)

        S.text = NSString(format: "Score : %i", Score as CVarArg) as String
        HS.text = NSString(format: "Highcore : %i", Highscore as CVarArg) as String
    }
```

Comment: Your labels are not wide enough to show the entire strings you're assigning.  How are you controlling the widths of your labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change the widths of your labels to value bigger than current value.